# How to set nowrap on a DIV? Especially containing many sub-DIVs

Tags: html, parallax, nowrap

I want to make the Parallax scrolling effect. I used the method below, but when the sub DIVs are added, it will wrap:

```
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;border:solid 1px ;">
        <div id="layoutArea" style="width: 9999px;background-color:White; padding:10px 10px 15px 10px;border:solid 0px ;">
              <div id = "sub1"></div>
              <div id = "sub2"></div>
              <div id = "sub3"></div>
              <div id = "sub4"></div>
              <div id = "sub5"></div>
              <div id = "sub6"></div>
              .......
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {display:inline;}
</style>
```